# Android: how to override ContentProvider's ParcelFileDescriptor openFile method to send file from url as attachment via email?

Tags: android, email, url, attachment

i've searched a lot but did not stumble upon something like i have to do.
So when i click to send email file is shown as attached but i never receive attached file
Is there some special way to send attachments that you receive as URL?
Here is my activity code: http://pastebin.com/uzdJYxab[2]
And here is my project https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-91m-6ZevwCRTYtYXRGb3l6UVE/edit?usp=sharing
Code for "Send email" button:
  sendEmail_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                            intent.setType("*/*");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment from app");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sending mp3 file " + title);

                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"some_email@email.com"});
                            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

                            uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(trackUrl)));

                            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
                    }
            });
```

Maybe there has to be some other way to put audio file from URL to intent? I do have to use intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); as a part of my task. However i skipped another part

> ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE would use external activity which should access sound file. To allow such access you need: - Create ContentProvider. - Override public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)

Does this mean that only with a use of content provider can i get and put file from url as email attachment? I googled but did not find how to correctly override public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode), maybe someone will at least point me in right direction? Again i'm not asking to solve this, but at least point me out my mistakes and give some advise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a content provider if the files are in a public directory. I do it in this way :

```
private void launchShareActivity(final List<String> exported_filenames) {
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "launchShareActivity");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    if (exported_filenames.size() == 0) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "there no file to share");
        return;
    }
    final ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for (final String exported_file : exported_filenames) {
        final File f = new File(exported_file);
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(f));
    }
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send page"));
}
```

Comment: the thing is that files are streamed from URLs, and i've yet to find a solution. Everything i found only covers getting and sending files from different folders. I get urls from xml file i had to parse, they go like this: http://wbads.vo.llnwd.net/o25/u/wbdd/vapp/thedarkknight/soundboard/German/TDK_Joker_better_class_GER.mp3. As you saw from my example:  uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(trackUrl))); does not allow attached file to arrive to email